# can't start eclipse after update - One or more bundles are not resolved

Tags: eclipse

After updating eclipse it doesnt start anymore, i get a window saying

An error has occured

with an reference to a log file (see below)

Any way to get this resolved?

---- Log File -----

```
!SESSION 2013-01-16 23:31:46.709 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20120914-1800
java.version=1.6.0_37
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/dorjeduck/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -keyring /Users/dorjeduck/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-01-16 23:31:48.877
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-01-16 23:31:48.877
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ui.ide_3.8.1.v20120828-165804.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.ide 2 0 2013-01-16 23:31:48.877
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface.text_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-01-16 23:31:48.877
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ui.console_3.5.100.v20120521-2012.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.console 2 0 2013-01-16 23:31:48.877
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface.text_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-01-16 23:31:48.878
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.junit_3.7.100.v20120523-1543.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.junit 2 0 2013-01-16 23:31:48.878
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface.text_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-01-16 23:31:48.878
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.ui_1.0.400.v20120523-2012.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.ui 2 0 2013-01-16 23:31:48.878
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface.text_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-01-16 23:31:48.878
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.ui_3.8.1.v20120814-144251.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.ui 2 0 2013-01-16 23:31:48.878
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface.text_[3.8.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-01-16 23:31:48.878
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui_3.6.100.v20120530-1425.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui 2 0 2013-01-16 23:31:48.878
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface.text_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-01-16 23:31:48.878
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.wst.common.ui_1.1.500.v200911190730.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.wst.common.ui 2 0 2013-01-16 23:31:48.878
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface.text_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-01-16 23:31:48.878
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.ui_5.4.0.201206111645.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.cdt.ui 2 0 2013-01-16 23:31:48.878
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface.text_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-01-16 23:31:48.878
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_20.0.3.v201208082019-427395.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 2 0 2013-01-16 23:31:48.878
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface.text_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-01-16 23:31:48.878
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.pde.ds.ui_1.0.200.v20120530-1435.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.pde.ds.ui 2 0 2013-01-16 23:31:48.878
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface.text_[3.3.0,4.0.0).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using MAC. I would suggest you to reinstall the Eclipse for MAC from the following [eclipse for osx](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=macosx) (only if you can afford to do it obviously). From the logs the issue seems to be related to missing plugins. The update may have deleted the older plugin?? Try installing the plugins that eclipse is complaining about like Jface etc manually and putting them under eclipse/plugin folder, and see if that brings down the error logs. Otherwise, the only option would be reinstalling. Eclipse sometimes gets really angry :)

Answer (score 1):

A number of people have [reported similar problems](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=391495). There are several suggestions in that thread, but no definitive solutions. Only one of the suggestions worked for me - it's a way to revert eclipse to a previous state from the command line. It comes from [this blog post](http://pweclipse.blogspot.com.au/2011/03/working-state-from-p2-update.html).

In a terminal:

1. Go to the folder containing your eclipse install
2. `ls -lt p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/<som_profile_name>.profile/`
3. In my case `<som_profile_name>` was `epp.package.java.profile`, in Paul's blog `SDKProfile`.
4. You should see files like `1372434812558.profile.gz`.
5. Choose a recent one with a date you feel sure is ok
6. Put together a command like:

   `eclipse -noSplash 
   -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director
   -repository file:$(pwd)/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/<som_profile_name>.profile
   -profile <som_profile_name>
   -revert 1372434812558`
7. If that doesn't work, try adding `-destination .` (I did it successfully with `-destination`, but I think it should work without)